# How would I recursively remove all elements in an unsorted list, that are smaller than a given int?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I've been working on this recursive approach but can't seem to figure it out. My approach: I decided to create a copy of the list and then remove the last element of the copy for the recursive call. I would also remove it from the actual list if the last item (of the copy list, which was my way of trying to loop through the list) is larger then the given int.

```
public MyList<Integer> reduceMyList(MyList<Integer> m, int e) {

MyList<Integer> res = new MyDynamicList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) {

    res.addElement(i, m.getElement(i));
}

int scenario = 0;

if (m.length() <= 1) {

    scenario = 1;
} else {

    scenario = 2;
}

switch (scenario) {

case 1:
    if(res.length() == 0){
        System.out.println();
        break;
    }       

case 2:



    if (e <= res.getElement(res.length() - 1)) {

        m.removeElement(res.length() - 1);


    }
    reduceMyList(m, e);

    res.removeElement(res.length() - 1);

    break;
}
return m;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 public MyList<Integer> reduceMyList(MyList<Integer> m, int e) {
    if (m.size() == 0)
        return new MyDynamicList<>();

    MyList<Integer> subList = m.subList(0, m.size() - 1);// get the list without the last element
    Integer lastInteger = m.get(m.size() - 1);
    MyList<Integer> reducedList = reduceMyList(subList, e); // recursive call on sublist
    if (lastInteger <= e)
        reducedList.add(lastInteger);
    return reducedList;
}
```

Here you have a solution for your problem. Hope it will be usefull.

Comment: In the last if statement, shouldn't it be > instead of <=?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of interesting stuff going on in your code. First, it seems like you're using types as variables (MyList, MyDynamicList) and you haven't given us the definitions (they look like they just extend some List).  You probably don't need to define these things, although you can.  Second, there's no reason to use recursion for this.  But if you really want to, you could recurse, testing and removing one item along the way.  It's really just changing recursion into iteration and is kind of pointless (not to mention inefficient):

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyList extends ArrayList<Integer> {
    public void reduce(int e)
    {
        reduceAt(size()-1, e);
    }

    private void reduceAt(int pos, int e)
    {
        if (pos < 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (get(pos) < e) {
            this.remove(pos);
        }
        reduceAt(pos - 1,  e);
    }
}
```

Another way to use recursion would be to copy the list at each level of recursion and pass that to the next level, and then return the final list.  That would be even more inefficient.

To do it iteratively instead, you could use a method like this:

```
// iterating backward as that's more efficient when removing items
public void reduceIter(int e) {
    for (int i=size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (get(i) < e) {
            remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Given your comment and your answer to this question, if you want to recurse by removing and then re-adding an item in your original list, your function could look like this (note that your solution doesn't remove items below the value from your original list, as was asked for in the title of this question -- it produces a new list of items below the value):

```
public MyList<Integer> reduceMyList(MyList<Integer> m, int min) {

    if (m.length() == 0) {
        // not sure why you are printing, but here it is
        System.out.println();
        return new MyDynamicList<Integer>();
    }

    int value = m.getElement(0);
    m.removeElement(0);

    MyList<Integer> res = reduceMyList(m, min);
    if (value < min)
    {
        res.addElement(0, value);
    }

    m.addElement(0, value);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort put into this solution, I am using types and have a class for the definition of the dynamic list which has methods for adding, removing and getting elements as well as the length. I didn't want to include all the code or bog down with specific details as I have quite a few classes. I just wanted a explanation as to what I was trying to do wasn't working. As for why I am doing it recursively is because it is for a school project that states it is mandatory to use recursion. Apologises if the lack of information in the question made it hard to follow.

Comment: OK, trying to follow your logic -- in your solution, you are removing items from MyList but you indicated that MyDynamicList has the remove, add, and get?  Which class has which methods would affect the solution, but it sounds like you already solved it.  If you are interested, though, your code could be shortened considerably.

Comment: I have an interface: (called list) with get length, add element, remove element, get element. I have a class: (called dynamic list) which implements the interface, I have a class where I create the algorithm in and I have the class with the main in it. Thanks Paul any tips on shortening code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I need remove from the front of the list instead and that I was over complicating it, my bad. I used a new list to store the values of the elements that were smaller than the given int and returned that.

```
public MyList<Integer> reduceMyList(MyList<Integer> m, int e) {

    MyList<Integer> res = null;
    res = new MyDynamicList<Integer>();

    int scenario = 0;

    if (m.length() == 0) {
        scenario = 1;

    }

    else {
        scenario = 2;
    }

    switch (scenario) {

    case 1:

         System.out.println();
        break;
    case 2:

        int e0 = m.getElement(0);
        m.removeElement(0);

        res = reduceMyList(m, e);

        if (e0 < e) {

            res.addElement(0, e0);
        }
        m.addElement(0, e0);
    }
    return res;
}
```